# The hash sign next to ID

Tags: php, html

I've noticed most developer will add  hash sign `#`  next to id (`#253`) when it is used in a html page. what is the reason?

EDIT : I'm not talking about id attribute embedded in a html tag, but about presentation aspect , for example this is a table row that the end user would see:

```
id    name   family
#34   nina    janet
```

Comment: Are you serious ? take a look  https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Use the `id` attribute to link to an element with a specified id within a page:
e.g.

```
<h2><a id="top">Some heading</a></h2>

<p>Lots of text....</p>
<p>Lots of text....</p>
<p>Lots of text....</p>

<a href="#top">Go to top</a>
```

`#` is an id selector. similarly `.` is class selector.
See this for more info about selector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp